# JSSDK Unknown Host domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

With the new [Facebook changes on August 1, 2021](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/changelog) (I think) the Developer Dashboard > Facebook Login settings have been updated and now include a **Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK** section.

#### The Problem

I cannot add a **port number** to the domain like I can in the *Valid OAuth Redirect URIs* section. After clicking **Save Changes** the port numbers are removed from the entries. Our app is currently in development, and while serving the app from `https://www.example.localhost:4200` we are given the error while using the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript):

> JSSDK Unknown Host domain: The Domain you are hosting the Facebook Javascript SDK is not in your app's Javascript SDK host domain list. Please specify your host domain in App dashboard login settings.

[image: Facebook Error Image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The same problem, but I used the field "Authorized domains for the JavaScript SDK" with the URL and port and it works.

Here with your URL:
[image: FB App]

(I used Chrome english translation, sorry if the fields doesn't have the same words ;) )

Comment: I just tried saving this again and it worked. I was able to add the port number to the domain list!

Comment: How do you get to this page? I can't find these options

Comment: @dizazta : In Facebook Login / Settings section : https://imgur.com/a/LCD8lcP

Comment: To access this page, open your App Dashboard. Then, on the left, click on "Facebook Login" (in the "Products" area), then click on Settings.

Comment: Those settings are found here:
https://imgur.com/a/0ksvD1A

Comment: @elhef how can i find the port number of my website?

Answer (score 1):

It's December, 2023 and seems like things are different a bit.

In you app dashboard, click on `Use cases`, the `Customize` under `Authentication and account creation`

[image]

Click `Go to settings` under `Facebook login`

[image]

In this page you should be able to find `Allowed Domains for JavaScript SDK`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Started to have the same issue today.

The workaround that helped me is to use port 443 (default for HTTPS), in this case the origin has no port indicated in the URI and it passes "Allowed Domains for the JavaScript SDK" check.

Comment: This doesn't work in this case because the app I'm building is using Angular11 but utilizes a backend API being hosted on port 443 via Apache.

Answer (score 0):

As ii see you are using https on local, a few hours ago I am doing the same
then I shift my project to normal `http` and not on `https`, but due to this
facebook doesn't send the sensitive data and give if you see in setting then there is enforce `https` and its toggle option is disable in that case you can create your facebook login API app test version

[image]

after that I am able to use it on my project as it on `localhost:3000`.

Comment: I apprecate the suggestion, but our app uses OAuth to authenticate with Facebook. To disable the **Enforce HTTPS** option we must also disable OAuth, which doesn't help.