# JSSDK Unknown Host domain in Facebook Application

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-settings

We are using our subdomains dynamically with dynamic prefix from client and use those domains for facebook login but suddenly after their new policies from 1st Aug we are getting error message.

I am not able to add subdomain like `*.thebestlisting.com` because facebook have restricted to use wildcard characters and use absolute domains only.

Can someone suggest me any alternative option to use my all subdomains with dynamic prefix and how I can cover it with Facebook application.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you could only do that by sending users to your "main" domain first, have them login from there, and then pass the result back to your subdomain somehow. But then it would probably still not be a given that the rest of SDK functionality would work properly, it might f.e. not find cookies it relies on under the subdomain then.

Comment: In this link, the problem is solved
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932742/jssdk-unknown-host-domain